# Haskell: why I cant use liftM lines . getContents

Tags: haskell

I have `getLinesIn = liftM lines . getContents` than

```
readAndWriteIn = do
  list <- getLinesIn
```

and it doesnt work.
It says: Couldn't match expected type a0 -> m0 String with actual type IO String.
I dont understand why is that?
When I use `getLinesFile = liftM lines . readFile`
It works fine.
I need to do the same with getContents. Is there a way?

Thanks for any ideas.

EDIT:
Full output:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> m0 String'
            with actual type `IO String'
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `getContents'
In the expression: liftM lines . getContents
In an equation for `getLinesIn':
    getLinesIn = liftM lines . getContents
```

Comment: Paste the full compiler output

Comment: The error reads, roughly, as "the second argument of `(.)` must be a function (`a0 -> m0 String`) but it is not (`IO String`)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`readFile` is a function `FilePath -> IO String` while `getContents` is just `IO String` so you cannot use the `(.)` operator to compose it with `liftM lines`. You should just use

```
getLinesIn = liftM lines getContents
```

or

```
getLinesIn = fmap lines getContents
```